# How to compile the protofile

Tags: scala, scalapb

need a help, I don't have idea about how to compile for proto useing scalapb

```
syntax = "proto2";

package com.test;


import "ImageElement.proto";
import "Color.proto";

message BadgeBackground {
    optional string id = 1;

    oneof bg_oneof {
        ImageElement image = 2;
        com.test.Color bgColor = 3;
    }
}
```

how to compile the proto file in scalapb

Comment: Add scalapb plugin to sbt, put proto into `src/main/protobuf`, run `protobufGenerate` command or sth like that. It's in the documentation: https://scalapb.github.io/docs/installation